# Jquery offset is not giving the expected value if margin is used on body element in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contextmenu

I am trying to set the position of a `contextMenu` and using Jquery `jquery.ui.position`. For `ContextMenu` I am using this libaray:-

`https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo`

I am trying to position a `ContextMenu` as follow:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.contextMenu({
        selector: 'td[id="tdMenu"]',
        trigger: 'left',
        position: function (opt, x, y) {

            try {

                opt.$menu.position({
                    my: 'right top',
                    at: 'right bottom',
                    of: $("#tdDiv")
                });

            } catch (e) {

            }

        },
        items: {

            "0": { name: "Hi" },
        }
    });
});
```

HTML is as follow:-

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td id="tdDiv" style="background-color: yellow;">
                Menu Div
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td id="tdMenu">
                Click Here
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

In `IE 11` once the page will load and once I click on td with id `tdMenu` jquery.ui.position does not calculate the offset correctly. On second click it calcultes correctly.

What I have found is inside `jquery.ui.position` its calculating a offset as follow:-

```
function getDimensions( elem ) {
    var raw = elem[0];
    return {
        width: elem.outerWidth(),
        height: elem.outerHeight(),
        offset: elem.offset() // On first click its calculating wrong value and on second it calculates correctly.
    };
}
```

I have also given margin to body as:-

```
<body style="margin: 0px;">
```

If I will remove this margin it calculates correctly on first click also.

I cannot remove body margin. What can be the work around for this ?

Comment: do you have a separate `.css` sheet attached to your page ? if so, have you added a reset code ( which is `*{margin:0; padding:0}` ) at the very beginning of your `.css` ? if not, try that

Comment: i was going to say exact same thing. are you using any normalization or reset css. plz do that and check if helps. also make sure you have `*{box-sizing: border-box}` set.

Comment: It will help if you present a working jsfiddle ...otherwise your question is incomplete.

Comment: The main culprit was this portion `position: function` of `contextMenu`. For the first click only the `offset` inside `position` was different then the `offset` at the top of `document.ready`. At second click the offset was okay.

Answer (score 2):

From what you've posted, it looks like a classic case of computing an `offset` value before the page finished loading all styles and content, resulting in a wrong offset value at the time your `contextMenu` is initialized.

Replacing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // executes when DOM parser reaches </html> tag

  $.contextMenu({/* your stuff here */})
});
```

with

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  // executes when all external resources/references (images, scripts,
  // stylesheets, iframes, etc...) have finished loading

  $.contextMenu({/* your stuff here */ })
});
```

is likely to solve your problem, but without a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to test and make sure it works for your case.

---

**Note:** The above solution will delay the initialization of `$.contextMenu()` until the page has loaded. If your page takes a long time to load all its resources and you want to have `$.contextMenu` initialized before that moment, a workaround is to init it on `$(document).ready` and update it on `$(window).load`:

```js
function cMenu() {
    $.contextMenu({
      /* your stuff here */ 
    });
}
$(document).ready(cMenu);
$(window).on('load', cMenu);
```

In reality, chances are there is only one item in the page which influences that offset (most likely a stylesheet). If you which one it is (by elimination, disabling stuff in your page), you don't even have to wait for the rest to load, you can simply bind the re-run of your function on that elements' `onload` event.

Comment: The main culprit was this portion `position: function` of `contextMenu`. For the first time only the offset inside position was different then the offset at the top of document.ready. Once I will click again the offset will be okay.

Comment: I have already tried on('load') but only at the first click offset was different inside position while at second it was okay.

Comment: So I have calculated the `offset` at `document.ready` and assigned it to `offset` inside `getDimensions`. But this was a work around not a proper solution.

Comment: Without a [mcve] I can't inspect, therefore I can't debug.

Answer (score 1):

Remove body style before `contextMenu` event `show` and reset body style after `activated` event.

You can try something like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bodystyle = '';
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: 'td[id="tdMenu"]',
        trigger: 'left',
        events: {
               show : function(options){
                    bodystyle = $('body').attr('style');   
                    $('body').attr('style','');            
               },

               activated : function(options){
                    $('body').attr('style', bodystyle ) ;            
               }
        }
        position: function (opt, x, y) {

            try {

                opt.$menu.position({
                    my: 'right top',
                    at: 'right bottom',
                    of: $("#tdDiv")
                });

            } catch (e) {

            }

        },
        items: {

            "0": { name: "Hi" },
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The main culprit was this portion `position: function` of `contextMenu`. For the first time only the offset inside position was different then the offset at the top of `document.ready`. Once I will click again the offset will be okay.

Comment: So I have calculated the offset at document.ready and assigned it to offset inside `getDimensions`. But this was a work around not a proper solution.